# How to index documents in elastic search?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have few millions of (pdf, docx, doc) files and each file may contain around 2-4 pages of text.

My problem is that I have a use-case where I have a document and I want to get similar documents from those millions of files. (i.e., match one document with all others and get n-matches)

Can I use elastic-search, is it scalable?  How should I index documents in this case? Do I just extract text from pdf document and store it in json object and insert as document to a index using elastic search.

Is this the most efficient solution?

Comment: Suggest you to read the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371668/what-is-a-convenient-way-to-do-document-clustering-with-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

You may use filebeat agent (part of ELK Stack) to install into source server where files are generated. It can export all documents to kafka topic (so that it retains) there. In Elastic you can create pipelines to pull, parse , match and transform the data you want to do. You can also create multiple pipelines based on group-id so each new pipeline can pull same set of data again, and parse/match/transform based on new logic.
Its scalable, and reliable for future.

Comment: While Kafka is a good recommendation, it doesn't really address the question of actually processing the files. Filebeat doesn't work too well on binary document types, either